# Response.BinaryWrite() in ASP.Net MVC Test Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tdd, moq

I am stuck in a situation, in which i am creating a test project in ASP.Net MVC, here i am testing a Method which is actually using to download a file, so whenever i am trying to test this method it gives

> OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used

Error in `Response.BinaryWrite()`, everything is fine except this, can anyone tell me how to resolve this exception, i am using **MOQ** dll for Mocking, Please suggest me to get rid of this situation.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite()
```

This is the line which is actually generating exception, now i have a question that- Is this good to test a download method or i have to leave it, if it is good then how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're mocking your HttpContext, then HttpContext.Current will be null in a test project, much less the response object

Comment: I tend to avoid mocking libraries such as the HttpContext. Mocking these libraries is generally not worth the effort IMO. If the HttpContext is an issue, you could extract your code into a method and unit test that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a unit test you generally don't want to be writing a test that have dependencies that  you can't control (e.g. writing to the database, filesystem or output stream).  You can also assume that the Response.BinaryWrite does what it is supposed to.

You could do something like this to get around the error you are seeing.

```
public interface IBinaryWriter 
{
  void BinaryWrite(byte[] buffer);
}

public class ResponseBinaryWriteWrapper : IBinaryWriter
{ 
  public void BinaryWrite(byte[] buffer)
  {
     HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);    
  }
}
```

This will give you the ability to inject the IBinaryWriter into the class you want to test as a mock and then you can check that BinaryWrite is called with the correct byte array.  In your production code you then inject your concrete ResponseBinaryWriterWrapper class.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks Andrew, your sounds like good, you are moving me to use dependency injection, now i am sure definitely it will help me out, 
i'll try it.any ways thanks for your reply.